# ScaleY not work when using a Slider to Zoom in a Canvas WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, debugging

need help to understand why my code doesn't work
XAML Only (no code behind)

```
<Window x:Class="Chapter02.ScaleInCustomSystem"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Scale In Custom System" Height="310" Width="260">
    <StackPanel Height="280" Width="250">
        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Height="200" Width="200" Margin="20">
            <Canvas Height="200" Width="200">
                <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <ScaleTransform ScaleY="-1"/>
                        <TranslateTransform Y="200"/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Canvas.RenderTransform>

                <Line X1="0" Y1="0" X2="80" Y2="80" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2">
                    <Line.RenderTransform>
                        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding ElementName=slider, Path=Value}"
                                        ScaleY="{Binding ElementName=slider, Path=value}"/>
                    </Line.RenderTransform>
                </Line>

                <Rectangle Canvas.Top="100" Canvas.Left="30" Width="80" Height="40" Stroke="DarkRed" StrokeThickness="3">
                    <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding ElementName=slider, Path=Value}"
                                        ScaleY="{Binding ElementName=slider, Path=value}"/>
                    </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                </Rectangle>
            </Canvas>
        </Border>

        <Slider Name="slider" Minimum="0" Maximum="3" Value="1" TickPlacement="BottomRight" TickFrequency="0.2" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

When I run this code, the slider only scale the image on the x axis, and the y axis doesn't do anything, when I only run the code with the ScaleY argument, it does nothing.
What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Just to clarify, I took this code from a book that I'm reading to learn WPF. Book name is "Practical WPF Graphics Programming".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `value` with `Value`. It's case sensitive

```
ScaleY="{Binding ElementName=slider, Path=Value}"/>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, and sorry for not noticing it before and causing trouble here.